# DsMakeSpn Always Fails on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory, windows-server-2008

What could be the reason for consistent failure when calling DsMakeSpn?
The error code is 87.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Maybe you should post a sample code snippet so that someone familiar with this function can help you with debugging your parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been pinpointed:
The SPN in ADSI was written in upper case letters, when the function parameters (ServiceName) were written in lower case.

Anyway - does someone know what can cause ADSI to be case sensitive?

Thanks.

Comment: c++ is a case sensitive language.

Comment: But ADSI? Is ADSI case sensitive too?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is not Windows Server 2008 itself.  Here is some information about your [error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28VS.85%29.aspx) from MSDN:

> ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87 (0x57)  The parameter is incorrect.

Make sure your parameters are correct.

---

After making sure your parameters are correct, see if you need elevated permissions to perform the action.  The security model in Windows 2008 is more restrictive than Windows 2003.  Try running your program with elevated permissions by right-clicking and choosing "Run as administrator".  If you need to debug as administrator, you can right click on your IDE and run it as administrator.

Comment: Thanks,
All parameters should be correct -- it works when the AD is on Windows server 2003.

Comment: Besides, it runs with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Is the DC you're contacting a Read-Only Domain Controller (RODC)?  This is new to Windows 2008.  Also, there is a specific permission that controls whether you can set SPN's on an object.  Is this a host-based service?  What are the specific parameters (abstracted is fine)?